# Top 5 baby names in Texas in a time span (python)

Tags: python, list, sorting, dictionary

I had this program in Python regarding baby names in Texas. Solved quite a bit of it, but got stuck in the counting part. I converted the list to the dictionary. The output has to be such that the program displays the top 5 most popular baby names in the time span provided by the user (begin year, end year).

```
def count_names(file_data, begin, end, sex):

    import operator as op
    x=[]
    c=[]
    a=[]
    t=[]
    number_names = 5
    for d in range (begin,end+1):
        x.append(str(d))    
    for y in file_data:
        if y[5:9] in x:
            c.append(y)
    for q in c:
        p=q.split(',')
        if (p[1]=='M'):
            t.append(p)
        elif(p[1]=='F'):    
            a.append(p)               
    if(sex=='M'): 
        dm={}
        for h in t:
            dm[h[3]]=h[4]

    elif(sex=='F'): 
        df={}
        for j in a:
            df[j[3]]=j[4]  

def main():
#Open the data file and save the data in a list called file_data. 
#Each element of the list is a string in the format:
# 'TX,GENDER,YEAR_OF_BIRTH,BABY_NAME,OCCURRENCES\n'
    file_data = open('TX19010-2016.csv').readlines()
    sex = 'M'
    cmd = ''
    while cmd != 'quit()':
        cmd = input('> ')
        if cmd == 'girl':
            sex = 'F'
        elif cmd == 'boy':
            sex ='M'
        elif cmd != 'quit':
            years = cmd.split()
            begin = int(years[0])
            if len(years) > 1:
                end = int(years[1])
            else:
                end = begin
            count_names(file_data, begin, end, sex)

main()
```

Comment: Is this python? If so, please tag it as such.

Comment: Yes it's python.

Comment: So what's the problem? Where are you stuck? You've given us a bunch of code, most of which probably isn't relevant, with no pointers to where in that code you need help. Read [mcve] in the help, which has some good advice on how to ask a question—it really is a bit of a pain (and deceptively so) to learn how to use StackOverflow effectively, which is why they wrote all those help pages.

Comment: if(sex=='M'): 
        dm={}
        for h in t:
            dm[h[3]]=h[4]

    elif(sex=='F'): 
        df={}
        for j in a:
            df[j[3]]=j[4]
I am stuck in this part. I converted it to a dictionary and it is displaying the most popular names by year. I need it to count the names for a given range of years. I can't understand how to count the frequency of the names throughout the time period input.

Comment: Hard to read your code with just single characters for all variables. Maybe just print out your dictionary structure.